# Unmanaged installation and Entities data

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

I have unmanaged solution installed in un online prod environnement and I want to install a new version of this solution in the same environnement, my question is that if I do that, what will happen to my data entities as I don't want to lose my data from the environnement?
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4):

The data in the base tables will be not be altered when importing a new solution. 
It will be the entity definition.

If a new attribute has been created for an entity which is set to `Business Required` then a null value will be held until a user opens the form which will require that value to be supplied before the record can be updated.

Answer (score 3):

+1 to Stefan's answer.  I will also add that unmanaged solutions will never delete any data.  It is always additive, so if you remove an attribute from an entity in your solution in dev, it will not be removed when you import it into another environment.  You'll need to manually track these removals and remove them post solution deployment.